# System resets when selecting "Install alongside Windows Vista"

Tags: installation, wubi, restart, windows-vista

I have a pretty weird problem with Ubuntu 11.10. I am using a Live CD of it to install it alongside Vista, but when I click on "Install alongside Windows Vista", it just resets. I've tried installing Ubuntu 11.10 before, but it gave me a black screen after booting my laptop up and choosing Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, so I deleted it's partition and now I'm trying to install it again. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I would try burning the Live CD again. Sometimes there can be small errors that cause problems like this.

Other than that I imagine it could be any number of things.

Comment: Thanks Jay! I managed to install it from a pendrive, but it still has issues with booting (I'll post a different question for this).